# Cropping audio files?

Tags: audio, crop

I was wondering if there was a tool similar to [jCrop](http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/13/index.php), with the exception that instead of an image I'd allow the user to crop an audio file? Google didn't give me any useful results sadly :(

The reason why I'm asking is that I'm making a tool to convert audio files to popular ringtone formats, and only letting the user specify the offsets in numbers is somewhat inconvenient. Obviously the tool doesn't have to be in javascript - anything that fits into a website is ok.

Comment: This isn't a fully-developed answer, but I'll post it here anyway: you could always use something like FFmpeg to do the actual trimming on the server (e.g. `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:01:00 -acodec copy out.mp3` to get 1:00-2:00) and use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag with the `currentTime` JS property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement) to allow the user to play the media to find the offsets interactively.

Comment: @Lucas Jones That's what I'm already doing - the cropping is done server side, all I want is a frontend for the user to define offsets easily

Comment: Ah, OK. I can't suggest anything more sophisticated than hooking up a jQuery UI slider! Which isn't a particularly good solution either in terms of usability or aesthetics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a browser-based audio editor written in Flash that you could probably adapt (it supports cropping):

http://www.hisschemoller.com/2010/audio-editor-1-0/

One thing I found a bit confusing is that you have to hold down the play button on the editor to play the full sound.